# Python and IronPython on same machine?

Tags: python, ironpython

I am a total newbie in the Python world.

I want to start to experiment with Python and IronPython and compare the results.

Is it possible to install Python and IronPython on the same machine with interfering each other or is it better to do this in the virtual machine.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Python and IronPython are completely different applications that happen to implement (almost) the same language.

Answer (score 1):

Should be no problem, they have different executable filenames also.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could even install different versions of cPython interpreter (2.5, 2.6, 3.0, etc).